# How to understand ' I am of big eye'?

Tags: meaning, sentence, syntactic-analysis

'I am of big eye' means 'I am a person whose eye is big' ? Furthermore, how to understand the usage of 'somebody/thing is of something'?

Comment: Off hand, I'd say "no". Is this a quote from something? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Did you read this somewhere? If so, please give the full citation and context.  If not, then where did you come up with it from? It sounds . . . a bit off.

Comment: Are you sure that wasn't Big Sky (a town in Montana)? I've never heard the "big eye" expression.

Comment: Offhand I'd say "yes", but that "big eye" is figurative, but to understand how that figurative use works would as @tchrist says need more context. (I hope we get it, because I'm curious).

Comment: "I am of big eye" is probably meaningless to the average US listener.  I would be most likely to assume you were talking about some sort of cult or oriental mystic religion.  "ThingA is of ThingB" is not a common construction with a well-established meaning in English.  When used it would usually be assumed to be figurative, lacking any further context.

Comment: I'm curious too, and my best guess at a mishearing is "I am a big guy."

Comment: The closest saying that comes to mind is "sad of eye" from Nature Boy by Nat King Cole, which basically means "has sad eyes", but I don't think I've ever seen "of big eye" or "big of eye".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the structure that you are referring to - '[thing/person] is of [adjective] [attribute]' - is typically used as follows: '[thing/person]'s [attribute] is [value].'

For example, I can say, "I am of height 6'." This means "My height is 6'."

Another example: "The earthquake is of magnitude 5." This means "The earthquake's magnitude is 5."

I agree with your intuition about the meaning of "I am of big eye," although I have never heard that sentence structure used that way before. As other posters have suggested, it may have a unique meaning, but more context would be needed to determine that.

Comment: Your height example doesn't work that well for me. The expression that leaps to mind is "to be of sound mind and body".